# Is this a bug or expected behavior of glGetTexParameterIuiv?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a problem with OpenGL code that only appears with Intel UHD GPUs/drivers (tried with different UHD and driver versions (Builds 26.20.100.7810, 27.20.100.8190)).

Basically `glGetTexParameterIuiv(name, GL_TEXTURE_TARGET, &textureTarget)` seems to not work at all. It always gives a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.

The driver reports OpenGL 4.6, the specs say GL_TEXTURE_TARGET is supported from v4.5 (with Nvidia drivers it works as expected, i.e. I get the type of the texture)

This is sample code reproducing the problem:

```
GLuint tex1;
glGenTextures(1, &tex1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

GLuint tex2;
glGenTextures(1, &tex2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, tex2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);
GLenum rslt1 = GL_INVALID_ENUM;
GLenum rslt2 = GL_INVALID_ENUM;

glGetTextureParameterIuiv(tex1, GL_TEXTURE_TARGET, &rslt1);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
glGetTextureParameterIuiv(tex2, GL_TEXTURE_TARGET, &rslt2);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
```

With Intel drivers the assertions fail. My question is now: IS it a bug? Or am I missing something and the NVidia driver is just more forgiving?

Comment: Probably not the problem, but the last parameter of glGetTextureParameterIuiv should be  a `GLuint *` and not `GLenum *`.

Comment: If you're using OpenGL 4.6, why would you *need* to query the texture target? The DSA APIs don't need them, and you can use `glBindImageTexture(s)` instead of `glBindTexture`, which also doesn't take a target.

Comment: @NicolBolas The first target that a texture was bound to defines it's type. The purpose of the code is to find that type.

Comment: @Tom: I know what the target *means*; I don't know why you *care*. DSA took out all of the functions where you have to specify the type of the texture; all of the DSA APIs figure out what you mean by looking at the texture's type internally. So why do you need to query the texture's type?

Comment: @NicolBolas Because I need to read from it (framebuffer attachment). So in case of a GL_TEXTURE_MULTISAMPLE_2D I need to blit it first into a temporary texture/buffer before and then read from that. Also I can't rely on DSA API to be available, so I only use it where no alternatives exist and otherwise branch into ugly workaround solutions. My branching is based on the OpenGL version, which brought me to the problem described here...

Comment: @Tom: "*I can't rely on DSA API to be available*" But the `GL_TEXTURE_TARGET` parameter we're discussing is from GL 4.5. In fact, it's from ARB_DSA itself. If you're querying for it, then you are *already relying* on DSA. Also, blitting doesn't require knowledge of the texture target.

Comment: @NicolBolas: What's your point? As I said, I cannot rely on DSA. So - IFF I find it - I use this one call as there's no *cheap* way to find out the texture type otherwise. But there is one. That's my "ugly branch". All the following code is v3. And I *need* to know the texture type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code sample on AMD, NVIDIA and Intel (HD Graphics 630) drivers at hand - and only the latter one failed with error on calling `glGetTextureParameterIuiv()`, and I also don't see from function description a reason for this misbehavior. Tested with `GL_ARB_debug_output`, which doesn't give more information.

I believe that OpenGL 4.5+ support in current Intel drivers is misleading and broken (it would be good adding the driver version in your question, to track if the problem will be fixed in newer drivers).

How driver could report supporting particular OpenGL version and not providing complete set of functions defined by this version? For instance, all Intel drivers I've checked do not expose `glGetnCompressedTexImage` function, which is [not optional for OpenGL 4.5](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetCompressedTexImage.xhtml).

For this reason (missing symbols), my application reports error for Intel drivers pretending to support OpenGL and fallbacks to OpenGL 4.4.

Note that some OpenGL drivers may fail when calling glGet* function with different type, and success for others. But it doesn't look like this case.

Comment: "*I believe that OpenGL 4.5+ support in current Intel drivers is misleading and broken*" Intel drivers broken? Must be a day ending in "Y"...